# Solr 6 DateRangeField search exact match

Tags: solr, date-range, solr6

I have `salesperson` index which has `availableDateRange` as multivalue dateRangeField.
Following is the schema for `availableDateRange` field

```
<fields>
    <field name="availableDateRange" type="daterange" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false"/>
</fields>
<types>
    <fieldtype name="daterange" class="solr.DateRangeField"/>
</types>
```

If I search for available salesperson from 2017-07-15 to 207-07-17 as below

```
avalableRange:"[2017-07-15 TO 2017-07-17]"
```

In search result I am getting 2 result as below :

```
availableRange: [
    "[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-07-15T00:00:00Z]",
    "[2017-09-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z]"
]
availableRange: [
        "[2017-07-17T00:00:00Z TO 2017-07-19T00:00:00Z]"
]
```

Currently searching dateRange [2017-07-15 TO 2017-07-17] is showing me salesperson who is even available any of one matching day from 15-jul to 17-jul.

The current query is behaving like

```
availableRange:"2017-07-15" OR availableRange:"2017-07-16" OR availableRange:"2017-07-17"
```

**My question is:** How can I get all salespersons who are available on all the days of the searched range (i.e. all the days of mentioned date range 15,16,17 july)

query should behave something like :

```
availableRange:"2017-07-15" AND availableRange:"2017-07-16" AND availableRange:"2017-07-17"
```

But using AND is not a feasible solution, for big date ranges (for eg. 2017-01-01 TO 2017-12-31)

Can anyone help me please to findout a feasible and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `field` query parser for specify function (`op`) to deal with range field as range field (standard query parser consider `DateRangeField` as drop-in replacement for `TrieDateField`).

It can be specified as filter query `fq={!field f=availableRange op=Contains}[2017-07-15 TO 2017-07-17]` (or using `_query_` pseudo-field) where `op` can be `Contains`, `Intersects`, `Within`.

Default behavior is `Intersects`, for your particular case `Contains` seems to fit.

Comment: Thanks, seems working.
As reference to 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates

There are 3 rational predicates (i.e. Intersects (default), Contains, Within).
For more knowledge can you please tell me how can I use other 2 rational predicates ( i.e. Intersects (default), Within)